# How do I associate tables through the model and initializer

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm hoping to get a better understanding how to relate models to each other.  I'm also using seed data with entity framework.  However I think it have it set up incorrectly, and I'm not sure where.  When I try to run the index for company, I get a less than helpful error focusing on the CompanysToList.  Am I do something obviously wrong?  I'm lost at the moment

My db design is simple starting from the top and going down- admin, company, campaign, idea.

The following four classes are saved as individual classes in my model folders.

```
public class Admin
{

    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companys { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
}

public class Campaign
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CampaignID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Idea Idea { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Rank is within the idea model.

```
public enum Rank
{
    A, B, C
}

public class Idea
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int IdeaID { get; set; }
    public int CampaignID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Rank? Rank { get; set;}

}
```

then my seed data

```
    protected override void Seed(CeptContext context)
    {

        var admins = new List<Admin>
        {
        new Admin{AdminID=1, FirstName="Bob",LastName="Test"},
        new Admin{AdminID=2, FirstName="Fred",LastName="Tester"},

        };

        admins.ForEach(s => context.Admins.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var companys = new List<Company>
        {
        new Company{AdminID=1, CompanyID=101, CompanyName="Test Company",Website="www.testcompany.com",Description="Test Company"},
        new Company{AdminID=1, CompanyID=102, CompanyName="Big Company",Website="www.bigcompany.com",Description="big company"},
        new Company{AdminID=2, CompanyID=103, CompanyName="Big Technologies",Website="www.bigtechnologies.com",Description="Big technologies"},

        };

        companys.ForEach(s => context.Companys.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var campaigns = new List<Campaign>
        {
        new Campaign{AdminID=1, CompanyID=101, CampaignID=201, Description="New campaign"},
        new Campaign{AdminID=1, CompanyID=101, CampaignID=202, Description="New campaign2"},
        new Campaign{AdminID=1, CompanyID=102, CampaignID=203, Description="New campaign3"},
        new Campaign{AdminID=2, CompanyID=103, CampaignID=204, Description="New campaign4"},

        };

        campaigns.ForEach(s => context.Campaigns.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var ideas = new List<Idea>
        {
        new Idea{AdminID=1,CompanyID=101, CampaignID=201, IdeaID=301, Description="Big Idea", Rank=Rank.A},
        new Idea{AdminID=1,CompanyID=101, CampaignID=202, IdeaID=302, Description="Tiny Idea", Rank=Rank.B},
        new Idea{AdminID=1,CompanyID=102, CampaignID=203, IdeaID=303, Description="Idea to do great things", Rank=Rank.C},
        new Idea{AdminID=1,CompanyID=102, CampaignID=203, IdeaID=304, Description="Even bigger things", Rank=Rank.B},
        new Idea{AdminID=2,CompanyID=103, CampaignID=204, IdeaID=305, Description="Bad idea", Rank=Rank.C},
        new Idea{AdminID=2,CompanyID=103, CampaignID=204, IdeaID=306, Description="Other Idea", Rank=Rank.A},

        };
        ideas.ForEach(s => context.Ideas.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();


    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are these tables related correctly and does the seed data line up to this relation?

Comment: You shouldn't repeat these key fields down the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Gert, I felt like I was doing something wrong there, but I wasn't sure how to relate them then or how to associate them in the seed data.